# How fix error encoding BSON to MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, encoding, bson, mongodb-compass

I installed MongoDB Compass, and I get error message “An error occurred while loading navigation: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document”. I can’t create connection, and database.

- Version MongoDB Compass 1.28.1
- Version MongoDB 4.4.8
- Windows 10 Pro

I tried reinstalling a different version of MongoDB Compass but it didn't help.

On another other computer of the same configuration, everything seems to work, apparently some kind of problem in the OS

What could have happened?

P.S. Console commands work without problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can include information like: what is the version of Compass and MongoDB you are working with. Also, is your MongoDB server up and running. Are you able to connect to MongoDB from any other tools like mongo shell.

Comment: I added version information, also my server is running, and i can connect via other tools.

Comment: Also, the OS and version. You can try installing a previous version of Compass.

Comment: I tried reinstalling a different version, they all have the same problem. On another other computer of the same configuration, everything seems to work, apparently some kind of problem in the OS

Answer (score 1):

Try Mongo Compass 1.26.1 or previous versions or use Robo 3T, it will not throw UTF-8 errors. It will work.

If it is a mongo client db connection in node, then use following configuration

```
new MongoClient('<connection uri>', { enableUtf8Validation: false });
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/utf8-validation/)